# Lindelof and locally Euclidean implies second countable

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on Jack Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds and am thinking about Proposition 3.56 in the book:

> Suppose $P$ is a second countable space and $M$ is a quotient space of $P$. If $M$ is locally Euclidean, then it is second countable. [...]

This statement works great in the flow of text (which is excellent writing, I might add). After thinking about the proof for a little bit, I wonder if the following related proposition is also true:

> Let $M$ be a Linelof and locally Euclidean space, then $M$ is also second countable.

or simply, "Lindelof + locally Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ second countable". My argument would like this:

> Since $M$ is locally Euclidean, there exists a cover of it with coordinate balls. Since $M$ is also Lindelof, there is a countable subcover (with coordinate balls). Each coordinate ball is second countable and therefore $M$ is second countable.

Did I miss something in my argument? If not, this simple interaction between different topology conditions seems interesting to me.

Comment: It seems good to me.. In fact all that is required is that $M$ is locally second-countable.

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, all you need is that $M$ is Lindelof & first countable. Choose a sequencing of a countable decreasing basis of neighborhoods $\{U_n(x)\}$ at each point $x$, then for each $n$ take a countable subcover of $\{U_n(x)\mid x \in M\}$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair: This would imply that compact, first countable spaces are metrizable.

Comment: @Ulli - how so? Spaces can be compact and second countable without being Hausdorff.

Comment: If I understood your claim correctly, it says a Lindelof & first countable space is second countable. This implies that a compact (including Hausdorff), first countable space is second countable, regular, hence metrizable. The double arrow space provides a counter-example, isn't it?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair: May I just repeat? Your claim is false: the double arrow space is compact (hence Lindelof), first countable, but not second countable.

Comment: Several examples of compact Hausdorff first countable spaces that fail second countability: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=T_2%2BCompact%2BFirst%20Countable%2B~Second%20Countable

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is ok, but some step should probably be made more explicit at the end.

Expanding to the result as stated by @Tyrone:

> Lindelof + locally second countable $\implies$ second countable.

Starting just like you did, suppose $M$ is Lindelof and every point of $M$ has an open neighborhood that is second countable (in the subspace topology).  All these neighborhoods cover $M$, so by the Lindelof property we can choose a countable subcover $\mathcal U$.  Each $U\in\mathcal U$ is open in $X$ and admits a countable base $\mathcal B_U$ for its topology.  The union $\mathcal W$ of all the $\mathcal B_U$ for $U\in\mathcal U$ is a countable set of open subsets of $X$.

Now for the step that needs to be made more explicit.  To show that $\mathcal W$ is a base for the topology of $X$, take an arbitrary point $x\in X$ and an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ in $X$.  The point $x$ belongs to some $U\in\mathcal U$, and $U\cap V$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $U$.  Since $\mathcal B_U$ is a base for the topology on $U$, there is some $W\in\mathcal B_U$ with $x\in W\subseteq U\cap V$.  This provides some $W\in\mathcal W$ with $x\in W\subseteq V$, which completes the proof.